# Have problem while installing openGL ( using mesa-common-dev)

Tags: opengl, mesa

It says :

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
   mesa-common-dev : 
     Depends: libx11-dev but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libdrm-dev (>= 2.4.52) but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

This error occured because you are missing the packages required for installation of mesa-dev-common.

Open a new terminal session ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> ) and type the following command :

`sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libdrm-dev`

Try installing `mesa-dev-common` now. It should work just fine.